# SQL Query that updates multiple rows at once

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need help writing an update query that helps me clean up the following table. I have been doing each row manually and it is just long and exhausting process.

Is there a way to write an update query that updates the entire table all at once.

```
The rules:
1. All fields ending with m1 should only contain a value of 'aprn' 
2. All fields ending with m2 should only contain a value of 'pa'
3. If 'pa' does exist in a field ending with m1 then that means that field should be NULL and the value 'pa' should be moved to the m2 column. 


table_a
org_id org_name     a_m1   a_m2    b_m1     b_m2
1       north       aprn   pa      aprn     pa
2       south       null   null    pa       null
3       east        pa     null    pa       null
4       west        null   pa      null     pa


Correct: ORG_ID=1 (a_m1, a_m2, b_m1, b_m2)
Correct: ORG_ID=4 (a_m1, a_m2, b_m1, b_m2)
Correct: ORG_ID=2 (a_m1, a_m2)

Incorrect: ORG_ID=2 (b_m1, b_m2)
Incorrect: ORG_ID=3 (a_m1, a_m2, b_m1, b_m2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update table_a
set
a_m2 = case when a_m1 = 'pa' or a_m2 = 'pa' then 'pa' end
, b_m2 = case when b_m1 = 'pa' or b_m2 = 'pa' then 'pa' end
, a_m1 = case when a_m1 = 'aprn' then a_m1 end
, b_m1 = case when b_m1 = 'aprn' then b_m1 end
```

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/105d7/8).

It certainly works for your dataset. If this doesn't work for you, please add more details to your question.

Comment: You're welcome, @user1991499. If you find an answer helpful, please consider upvoting and/or setting it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question properly I suspect that multiple update statements might be best.  One of the things I like to do with statements that change the data is keep them simple.  I prefer to write multiple statements, have the RDBMS do more work, be slower, etc but always be right.  It can be hard to recover from a mistaken data change.

I am not sure I fully understand your criteria but something like the following.  If I do understand correct do you need to run 3. before 1. and 2.?

1. ```
   update table_a
      set a_m1 = 'aprn'
    where a_m1 = 'pa';
   ```
2. ```
   update table_a
      set a_m2 = 'pa'
    where a_m2 = 'aprn';
   ```
3. ```
   update table_a
      set a_m1 = NULL
      set a_m2 = 'pa'
    where a_m1 = 'pa';

   update table_a
      set b_m1 = NULL
      set b_m2 = 'pa'
    where b_m1 = 'pa';
   ```

Comment: @Andry.. Thanks, this is similar to what I have been doing, I was hoping to speed things up a bit but I guess dealing with data cleanup can't always be quick and easy.